# How to find a word in a json inside an array using js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
"links": [{
  "url": "http:...",
  "title": "3"
}, {
  "url": "http://facebook.com/pages/",
  "title": "2"
},{
  "url": "http://...",
  "title": "2"
}],
```

I want to find out of the array has the word 'facebook' and if so to take the specific url with the word and use it. I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
var arraylinks = mdata.links;
if (arraylinks[i].url === "facebook") {
    for (var i = 0; i < arraylinks.length; i++) {
        var klink = $("<a>").attr("href", arraylinks[i].url).attr('target', '_blank').addClass("icon-library");
    }
}
```

I would appreciate your help. thank you

Comment: well, `facebook` is only part of the full url, you could test it with `/facebook/i.test(arraylinks[i].url)` or something similar to make sure it actually contains the word facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you could do this:

```
var arraylinks = mdata.links;
for (var i = 0; i < arraylinks.length; i++) {
    if (arraylinks[i].url.indexOf("facebook") != -1) {    
        var klink = $("<a>").attr("href", arraylinks[i].url).attr('target', '_blank').addClass("icon-library");
        // do something with klink here
    }
}
```

I also think the for loop needs to be outside of the if statement

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to filter your list.

```js
var array = [{
  "url": "http:...",
  "title": "3"
}, {
  "url": "http://facebook.com/pages/",
  "title": "2"
},{
  "url": "http://...",
  "title": "2"
}];

var filtered = array.filter(function (obj) {
  return /facebook/i.test(obj.url);
})

console.log(filtered[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `indexOf` on the urls to keep it basic.

```js
var arraylinks = mdata.links;
var wordToFind = "facebook"
if (arraylinks[i].url && arraylinks[i].url.toLowerCase().indexOf(wordToFind) >= 0 ) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arraylinks.length; i++) {
    var klink = $("<a>").attr("href", arraylinks[i].url)
    .attr('target', '_blank').addClass("icon-library");
  }
}
```

Comment: True, you did, however the  only right answer I see is the one from [BrunoLM](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41527820/3231537) (though yours is the second best at the moment ;)).

Comment: Agreed, but i figured it's better to update my answer rather than removing it ;)

Comment: You're right, didn't realize the lines were reversed. Thanks @Icepickle

Comment: Your last edit is incorrect (run it in jsfiddle or something), link would be 0, 1, 2 (the property name of the array) (see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m42f0bfx/))

Comment: Fixed it again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
fbLink = links.find(function(el){
   return el.url.indexOf('facebook') >= 0 
});
```